# Sqoop command-How to give schema name for Import All Tables

Tags: hive, sqoop

I am importing all tables from rdbms to hive using the sqoop command(v1.4.6).
Below is the command

```
sqoop-import-all-tables --verbose --connect jdbcconnection --username user  --password pass  --hive-import  -m 1
```

This command works fine and it is loading all the tables in default schema.Is there a way to load the tables in particular schema?

Regards
Prakash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`--hive-database <db name>`** in your import query.

Modified command:

`sqoop-import-all-tables --verbose --connect jdbcconnection --username user  --password pass --hive-import --hive-database new_db -m 1`